# PyInstaller + Dash: could not locate package-info.json

Tags: python, pyinstaller, plotly-dash

I want to make a one-file exe from a python script using Dash.
I have an analogous app that uses flask and it works.
Using Dash instead, when I run the generated exe file, I get the following error and I can't solve it.
Could you help me?[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the exact same problem with the Temp folder, I don't know exactly why. I don't think I found the best solution, but I solved it by using a spec file for compilation and by adding all the packages that caused this error (all dash packages and plotly) to the `data` argument.

As explained [here](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html#adding-data-files), you can create a spec file to run pyinstaller like the command line instruction by running : `pyi-makespec options name.py [other scripts …]`, with options like `--onefile`.
It will create a spec file, with a Analysis constructor, where you can say to pyinstaller where to search for any package with a list of tuples `datas=[('<path to the package>', '<name of the package>'), ...]`.

Your error seems to come from dash for you so something like this, depending of where is the dash package you're using (for me in a venv) :

```
a = Analysis(['script.py'],
         pathex=[],
         binaries=[],
         datas=[('D:\\xxxxxx\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\dash', 'dash')],
         hiddenimports=[],
         hookspath=[],
         hooksconfig={},
         runtime_hooks=[],
         excludes=[],
         win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
         win_private_assemblies=False,
         cipher=block_cipher,
         noarchive=False)
```

If you use other dash packages like dbc or plotly I think you will have the same errors with those packages, so you'll have to add their path to the spec file too.

Comment: you were totally right: I had to append manually the dash package via `('venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\dash', 'dash')`

Answer (score 2):

This is the answer that worked for me: https://community.plotly.com/t/pyinstaller-error-when-executing-plotly-dash-exec-file/34126/10.

As in the post above, first do a `pyinstaller main.py --onefile` to make the spec file which you can edit like below. I didn't have the "dash_renderer," like in the link, so I'm posting mine below.

```
a = Analysis(['main.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\trucking_dashboard'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[
                ('C:\Python39\Lib\site-packages\dash', 'dash'),
                ('C:\Python39\Lib\site-packages\dash_bootstrap_components', 'dash_bootstrap_components'),
                ('C:\Python39\Lib\site-packages\dash_core_components', 'dash_core_components'),
                ('C:\Python39\Lib\site-packages\dash_html_components', 'dash_html_components'),
                ('C:\Python39\Lib\site-packages\dash_table', 'dash_table')
            ],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             hooksconfig={},
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
```